# Convert string with many dates to datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime

If my string consisted of just one date I'd use this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%b %d %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But since there are many along the string, I don't know how to proceed. How could I read the string and make the changes only where needed?

So here is my string:

```
s = 'Mar 27 2000*56.75*58.39*Mar 26 2000*53.10*56.13*Mar 25 2000*51.50*52.00'
```

and what I expect right after:

```
s = '2000-03-27*56.75*58.39*2000-03-26*53.10*56.13*2000-03-25*51.50*52.00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all string dates are in the same format, you could use a regex for obtaining the dates in the string and then replace it, I'm thinking of something like this:

```
import re
import datetime

def operate_on_replacement(matchObj):
    match = matchObj.group(0)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(match, '%b %d %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

start_string = 'Mar 27 2000*56.75*58.39*Mar 26 2000*53.10*56.13*Mar 25 2000*51.50*52.00'
replaced_string = re.sub(r'\w{3}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{4}', operate_on_replacement, start_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
new_s = s.split("*")
```

And then use your code on the columns that are datetime formated.